# What are some  upper-body cardio programs to increase endurance?

Tags: cardio, muscle-endurance, upper-body-workout

I'm looking to keep increasing my endurance when I can't do lower body exercises.  Are there any interesting high-intensity programs out there that don't rely on your legs?

For reference, Beachbody's Insanity and P90X Plyometrics are what I typically use for a cardio workout.  Ideally I'd like a similar level of interval/circuit training that I can do at home when my [knee](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/658/knee-strengthening-exercises) is cranky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a program.  But as a boxer I would suggest you try a speed bag and you could pair that with body weight hanging exercises.

Comment: Good idea!  Is there a resource I could check out for different routines to mix it up?  I've only done the basic "Rocky montage" bag work.  Incidentally, Wii boxing has been my fallback so far :)

Comment: Yea there are a million.  But I used to do this.  3 minutes of jabs(throw a punch every 2-3 seconds) 1 min rest. 3 minutes 1/2 (jab cross). 1 min rest 2.5 minutes mix it up hooks and for the last 30 seconds of round 2 short straight pucnches as fast as you can.  4 minute rest. 3 minutes fouces ball 1 min rest 2x3min speed bag

Answer (score -1):

I would say that doing rowing without weights, canoeing, kayaking, and throwing punches(wear gloves) at a bag are all forms of good upper body cardio.